# Can I login to gitlab's docker registry with a Group Token?

Tags: docker, gitlab

A Self-hosted GitLab Enterprise Edition 15.10.6-ee.

I've made a [Group access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html). Regarding the [Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html) I should be able to use this token to authenticate to the docker registry. But I cannot find a way to do it.
I am trying to use the command line: `docker login`, but there is no way I can provide only a token and not a username.

I guess the documentation is a bit misleading, as you cannot really use a Group token to login, at least not on the command line.
Or is there a way?

Comment: Thanks Moshe!
I was struggling with this for an hour now ;).

If you make this a reply, I can accept it as 'answer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitLab Docker Registry doesn't care what username you use. You do not need to use a specific name, only the token in the password field is checked.

Looking through the configuration on various PCs and servers, I see that I've used `token`, `ci-token`, `gitlab-token`, and a few other random strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat similar situation where we need to pull an image from our private registry for our CI jobs. And authentication to the registry needs to use a group access token.

```
image:
  name: registry.ofyourcompany.com/group_xyz/abc/docker-team-image:1b73586f
```

I was able to make it work using Moshe's hint above:

```
echo -n "RANDOM_USERNAME:<Group Access Token here>" | base64
```

And then I set the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable in the CI/CD setting in the Gitlab project:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.ofyourcompany.com": {
            "auth": "base64 value of username:token"
        }
    }
}
```